# How to check if the window is open or not?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am opening a window say "Window2" from main menu item(Command 2 under Window) . So, if the menu item is clicked again it opens the "Window2" again instead of making the existing window the key window and disabling corresponding menu item. Below is my effort on implementing that in my AppDelegate class, as variable "lmWindowController" always returning nil, instances of window2 is getting opened multiple times, what am I missing here?

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var lmWindowController: LocalisationMappingWindowController?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func showLocalisationMappingWindowController(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if (!(lmWindowController != nil)) {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "LocalisationMapping"), bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let windowController: NSWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "LocalisationMappingWindowController")) as? NSWindowController{
             windowController.showWindow(windowController.window)
             windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            }
        } else {
            lmWindowController?.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        }

    }
    
    override func validateMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) -> Bool {
        var enable = self.responds(to: menuItem.action)
        
        if menuItem.action == #selector(showLocalisationMappingWindowController(_:)) {
            for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
                if window.title == "Localization Mapping" {
                    enable = false
                }
            }
        }
        return enable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `showLocalisationMappingWindowController` a new `windowController` is loaded but `lmWindowController` isn't changed. Add `lmWindowController = windowController`.

```
@IBAction func showLocalisationMappingWindowController(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if (!(lmWindowController != nil)) {
        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "LocalisationMapping"), bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let windowController: NSWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "LocalisationMappingWindowController")) as? NSWindowController{
            windowController.showWindow(windowController.window)
            windowController.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            lmWindowController = windowController
        }
    } else {
        lmWindowController?.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Willeke This is working as expected, but how do I show the main window back? Since the main window is already loaded, how to check if it exists?

Comment: @GaganaSAchar I don't know, please ask a new question.